# Python + VLC + RTSP - cannot take screenshot

Tags: python, vlc, rtsp

I have a code, which must to take screenshot from rtsp stream

```
def get_screen():
    player vlc.MediaPlayer('rtsp://###')
    player.play()  
    player.video_take_snapshot(0, 'screenshot.tmp.jpg', 0, 0)
get_screen()
```

Once I launch it I got `Process finished with exit code 0` in the shell

But there is no `screenshot.tmp.jpg` in the folder, which I want to have.

Why?

I want to get screenshot.tmp.jpg file

Comment: There are some other possible problems here, like an async process being unable to complete because you exit without blocking to let it complete -- but before we get to that, have you tried using an absolute path? We don't know which folder "the folder" is, and you'd be surprised how many people are unclear on the concept of "current working directory" as distinct from the location of the code being run.

Comment: (also, make sure your code is syntactically valid and demonstrates the exact error you want to showcase when run -- right now I assume you want `player = vlc.MediaPlayer(...)`, but the `=` isn't present as given; it would also help reproducibility to point to a built-in input source rather than an invalid RTSP URI that can't actually be used)

Comment: player = vlc.MediaPlayer(...)   - yes, my bad. But it still does not work. I ahve removed actual URL for security

Comment: We don't need _your_ actual URL, but we need _some_ actual URL or else we can't test the issue without setting up our own RTSP server, and nobody can be reasonably expected to do that. (Does the problem still take place when instead of playing from a RTSP stream you play from a static file? That's all the more accessible of a reproducer, if so); and if it _only_ happens with a RTSP server or other remote source, that's a clue as to the problem in and of itself.

Comment: Anyhow, about the question of whether the action is synchronous or not -- does putting in a delay between requesting the screenshot and exiting address the problem?